# Run * operator asynchronously and cancel it

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout, operator-overloading, cancellation

I overloaded * sign for one of my classes. Based on operands it may take long (CPU-Bound) so I want to run it asynchronously with a timeout.

```cs
MyClass o;
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task<MyClass> task = Task.Run(() => o1 * o2, cts.Token);
Task timeout = Task.Delay(10000);

if (await Task.WhenAny(task, timeout) != task)
{
    cts.Cancel();
    throw new TimeoutException();
}

o = task.Result;
```

It throws the exception after 10 seconds however it won't cancel the operation because there is nothing to check `cts.IsCancellationRequested` and app uses a lot of CPU trying to finish the task.

One solution is to create a method like `Multiply(MyClass m, MyClass m1, CancellationToken ct)` but overloading operator is much more funny and makes code look cleaner. (:

Isn't there any way to cancel the task? For example by forcing an exception in it?

Comment: "overloading operator is much more funny" - and introduces expectations such as "this operation will complete quite quickly". Having a method accepting a cancellation token really is the clearest approach here.

Comment: _"and makes code look cleaner."_ - actually, I'd like to disagree in this case. You totally surprise a client by the * operator taking longer than a blink of an eye to execute. I also don't know what "MyClass" is modelling but I hope "*" is unambiguous abot what the result is going to be?

Comment: "however it won't cancel the operation because there is nothing to check `Token.IsCancellationRequested`" - it is technically checked by `Task.Run`, but only when initially starting/determine when to run the task.  I'm curious what `CancellationToken ct = default` would return here -- as an optional parameter to an overload method that your override operand would call to.

Comment: @Fildor The name of `MyClass` is actually something else. The * actually does multiplication and everybody can understand what does it mean. However you and @JonSkeet are right about speed expectation...